# laravel how yo include on menu button click in the samepage

Tags: php, laravel

I have menu on the right and want to display when click on specific item button specific page so how can I make include if only I clicked on this item button

```
<a href="{{route('customer.package')}}">
    <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
    <span>Update Your Package</span>
</a>        
@include('index.customer.customerpackage')
```

Comment: You could use the jquery for this. like as:
<a class="custom-menu" href="{{route('customer.package')}}" style="display:none;">
                      <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
                      <span>Update Your Package</span>
                  </a>
<button id="button">Click</button>
<javascript>$(document).ready(function(){$('#button').click(function(){
$('.custom-menu').show();
});})</javascript>

Comment: I want to @include    @include('index.customer.customerpackage')

Comment: That's not possible, include is processed by Blade when the view is being compiled during the page load. You have to @include the required pieces inside, for example, hidden <div>'s and then show them via javascript when user clicks on those <a> elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery for this. like as:

```
<a class="custom-menu" href="{{route('customer.package')}}" style="display:none;">
                      <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
                      <span>Update Your Package</span>
                  </a>
<button id="button">Click</button>
<javascript>$(document).ready(function(){$('#button').click(function(){
$('.custom-menu').show();
});})</javascript>
```

Comment: If you want to use this as : @include('index.customer.customerpackage') then the customerpackage.blade.php file should be in resource/views/index/customer directory

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('customer.package')}}"">
   <i class=""></i>
   <span>Update Your Package</span>
</a>
```